# Can not query a single resource after upgrading JSONAPI.NET to latest version (0.3.0-pre-1)

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, json-api

I can not query single resource (i.e. /{controller}/{id}) after upgrading JSONAPI.NET to latest version (0.3.0-pre-1). I can query all multiple resources end-points (i.e. /{controller}).

It might be related with the `JSONAPI.EntityFramework.Http.ApiController` because I have created a controller using the `System.Web.Http.ApiController` and it works fine. I used the same DbContext.

I have followed/tried all the code from [JSONAPI.TodoMVC.API](https://github.com/SphtKr/JSONAPI.NET/tree/master/JSONAPI.TodoMVC.API).

Here is the error I get:

```
{
"errors": [
    {
        "id": "6b49c8a9-d7b4-473e-80cd-c771fe1e7d13",
        "status": "500",
        "title": "System.AggregateException",
        "detail": "One or more errors occurred.",
        "inner": {
            "id": null,
            "status": "500",
            "title": "System.ArgumentException",
            "detail": "The Type AssetClass was not found in the DbContext with Type ApiContext",
            "inner": {
                "id": null,
                "status": "500",
                "title": "System.ArgumentException",
                "detail": "The member with identity 'ConeTec.DataServices.Web.Areas.WebApi.Models.AssetClass' does not exist in the metadata collection.\r\nParameter name: identity",
                "inner": null,
                "stackTrace": "   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.ItemCollection.GetItem[T](String identity, Boolean ignoreCase)\r\n   at JSONAPI.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkMaterializer.GetKeyNames(Type type)"
            },
            "stackTrace": "   at JSONAPI.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkMaterializer.GetKeyNames(Type type)\r\n   at JSONAPI.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkMaterializer.GetKeyProperties(Type type)\r\n   at JSONAPI.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkMaterializer.GetByIdAsync(Type type, Object[] idValues)\r\n   at JSONAPI.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkMaterializer.<GetByIdAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at JSONAPI.Http.ApiController`1.<Get>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()"
        }
   }
]
```

}

Any idea why I get this error?

Thanks!

[S'pht'Kr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/489116/sphtkr)
@S'pht'Kr

[csantero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3754416/csantero)
@csantero

Here is the full error trace:

```
{
"errors": [
    {
        "id": "57a5f40e-b170-407f-982a-c7cad64539e9",
        "status": "500",
        "title": "System.AggregateException",
        "detail": "One or more errors occurred.",
        "inner": {
            "id": null,
            "status": "500",
            "title": "System.ArgumentException",
            "detail": "The Type AssetClass was not found in the DbContext with Type ApiContext",
            "inner": {
                "id": null,
                "status": "500",
                "title": "System.ArgumentException",
                "detail": "The member with identity 'ConeTec.DataServices.Web.Areas.WebApi.Models.AssetClass' does not exist in the metadata collection.\r\nParameter name: identity",
                "inner": null,
                "stackTrace": "   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.ItemCollection.GetItem[T](String identity, Boolean ignoreCase)\r\n   at JSONAPI.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkMaterializer.GetKeyNames(Type type)"
            },
            "stackTrace": "   at JSONAPI.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkMaterializer.GetKeyNames(Type type)\r\n   at JSONAPI.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkMaterializer.GetKeyProperties(Type type)\r\n   at JSONAPI.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkMaterializer.GetByIdAsync(Type type, Object[] idValues)\r\n   at JSONAPI.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkMaterializer.<GetByIdAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at JSONAPI.Http.ApiController`1.<Get>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()"
        },
        "stackTrace": "   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()\r\n   at ConeTec.DataServices.Web.Filters.ApiUserContextAttribute.ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 continuation) in c:\\CDS\\ConeTecGeoDb\\ConeTec.DataServices.Web\\Filters\\UserContextAttribute.cs:line 160\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
    }
]
```

}

Here is a example of my `AssetClassesController`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using ConeTec.DataServices.Web.Areas.WebApi.Models;
using JSONAPI.EntityFramework.Http;

namespace ConeTec.DataServices.Web.Areas.WebApi.Controllers {
    public class AssetClassesController : ApiController<AssetClass, ApiContext> {

    }
}
```

Comment: That is certainly an interesting one. This error should be thrown if you try to materialize a model type that isn't in your DbContext. But are you saying that you can successfully get `/assetclasses/` but cannot get `/assetclasses/42`? Is AssetClass one of the entities in your DbContext? Or was this the result of a request for some other entity, and AssetClass is a non-entity type that is returned from a member property?

Comment: Yes, right. I can access `/assetclasses/` but not `/assetclasses/42`. Yes, AssetClass is defined in my DbContext. Same problem for all the entities. I just created a new one (without any relationship) and I have the same problem. Everything works fine if my controller inherits from `System.Web.Http.ApiController`.

Comment: This is a tough one. I will have to have a close look at the code and see if I come up with any ideas. Only other thing that occurs to me is something causing it to not be able to load the entity metadata. Can you post your `ApiController` class, including your `using` statements?

Comment: One other question... It seems that the underlying error from Entity Framework can happen if model objects cross projects or assemblies... Is `AssetClass` defined in a different project than your `ApiController`? That might be a factor. Whatever is causing it, there is a way to workaround it. Make a subclass of `EntityFrameworkMaterializer` and override the `GetById` method. You can include logic there to get any of your models by ID. What is failing is EFM trying to figure out how to do that automatically. I'll post that with more detail as an answer tomorrow.

Comment: I posted my `AssetClassesController` as requested. `Models/Controllers/ApiContext` are all in the same project. It is all in an area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug should be fixed as of https://github.com/SphtKr/JSONAPI.NET/pull/77.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have AssetClass defined in your ApiContext class as `DBSet<AssetClass> AssetClass`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm air-coding...on my iPhone...but give this a try.

Make your own subclass of `EntityFrameworkMaterializer` and override the `GetKeyNames` method, something like this:

```
protected override IEnumerable<string> GetKeyNames(Type type)
{
    this.DbContext.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(this.DbContext.GetType().Assembly);
    return base.GetKeyNames(type);
}
```

Then in your `ApiController` override...

```
protected override JSONAPI.Core.IMaterializer MaterializerFactory()
{
    return new MyMaterializer(new ApiContext());
}
```

There are some inefficiencies with doing it just this way, but if that solves your problem then I can figure out what to do in the library.

As a backup plan, just use the overridden GetKeyNames method to return a List of the correct key names for each of your model types. (Hint: if this was working for you in 0.2.0 you're safe to simply return `new List<string> { "Id" }`, every time...because I discovered recently that's all that the old GetKeyNames method would ever do.) ;-)

Comment: Thanks S'pht'Kr. Loading from the Assembly as you suggested does not work. I opted for your other suggestion which is returning `new List<string> { "Id" }` and it is now working. However, it does not seem to be an optimal solution ;)

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but my Web API resides in an `Area`.

Comment: Not sure if it is related to this issue, but I can not include relationships in representation with `IncludeInPayload(true)`. Do you think it is related? There is no error returned, simply not included.

Comment: Very possibly related, but unknown. I was reading up on areas...as near as I can tell, the compiler and runtime knows nothing about them, they're strictly a MVC thing...meaning, EF shouldn't even know the difference. But I will research that further.

Comment: I have overridden `EntityFrameworkMaterializer.GetKeyNames` to look at  `System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.DataSpace.OSpace` instead of `System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.DataSpace.CSpace` and I can get single resource now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470345/how-to-get-dbsets-metadata-from-ef-codefirst-dbcontext