# How to get type of of the property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using entity frame work 6 code first approach in my project.

I try to get type of the property in contracts entity:

```
var t = _context.Contracts.Select(x=>x.ClientId).GetType();
```

`Contracts` is some entity that has `ClientId` property and defined in Context.

But `t` is null.

How can I get property type of Contracts entity.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you using a *query* to check a property's type instead of trying to access it through the DbSet, `Contracts`? Or simply through the Entity's type? Are you really looking for the DbSet's metadata perhaps?

Comment: is there alternative way?

Comment: People cannot understand what you are trying to get with that query. Try elaborating.

Comment: Something like `var t = _context.Contracts.GetType().GetProperty("ClientId").PropertyType`? *Reflection*?

Comment: Depends on *what it is that you want to do*.  A DbContext or ObjectContext provide access to the metadata [as shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470345/how-to-get-dbsets-metadata-from-ef-codefirst-dbcontext). Or you can simply use Reflection on `Contract`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko that would return `DbSet<Contract>` which doesn't have a ClientId. You'd need to extract the generic type parameter first

Comment: I need to get the type of the property!!!

Comment: @Michael which explains nothing at all. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? *Why* do you want the type of the property through the context? Why don't you simply write something like `typeof(Contract).GetProperty("ClientId").PropertyType` ? Why do you need to know the type at all instead of using the built-in validation, data annotation, binding features?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Single() or FirstorDefault()`

```
_context.Contracts.Select(x=>x.ClientId).Single().GetType();
```

Comment: That's *not* a good idea at all. That will force execution of the query, hitting the database to get information that is already available in code

Comment: I get error Sequence contains more than one element

Comment: @Michael trying this code is a very, very bad idea. There's absolutely no reason to execute a query when you already have the entity types available. But, *what are you trying to do*? Why do you want a property's type at all? There are a *lot* of ways to do whatever it is that you want if you explain it.